# Xamarin forms SignaturePad with UWP causes a CanvasDevice is not registered error

Tags: xamarin, signaturepad

(using PCL project)

I am using version 2.1 of the SignaturePad and works perfectly on Android, but on UWP, when I call the GetImageStreamAsync method, I get a 'Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.CanvasDevice is not registered' error.  I have tried both PNG and JPEG and both give the same error.

I was thinking something needed to be included in App.xaml.cs but looking at the samples, I don't see anything.  I did find a post where they added the assembly

```
     List<Assembly> assembliesToInclude = new List<Assembly>();                
            assembliesToInclude.Add(typeof(SignaturePad.Forms.SignaturePadCanvasRenderer).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
```

but I still get the same error.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
 SignaturePad.Forms.SignaturePadView SignPad = new SignaturePad.Forms.SignaturePadView()
        {
            StrokeWidth = 3f,
            StrokeColor = Color.Black,
            BackgroundColor = Color.White,
            HeightRequest = 200,
            WidthRequest = 400
        };

        // This gives error in UWP, but not Android:
        var image = await SignPad.GetImageStreamAsync(SignaturePad.Forms.SignatureImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: is Win2D installed?  see https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/87149/signature-pad-view-does-not-contain-getimage

Comment: As above, Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.CanvasDevice exists in Win2D. Try adding the Win2D nuget package to your project

Comment: That was it, I installed Win2D and that took care of it, thanks.